# Spinloop of slave processor

Tags: process, processor

In my system, I have a master processor and a slave processor. The slave processor on start up, continues to loop back in a self loop (a single mjump onto itself instruction). Is it normal for slave processors to behave in this way? What might be done to bring the processor out of this state?

Answer (score 0):

An interrupt could be used to do this. It may be used to redirect the slave to an ISR (interrupt service routine) independent of the normal flow of execution.

Another example may be for the master processor to change the jump instruction to send the slave somewhere totally different. This could even be done if it's in ROM if your hardware is complex enough (for example, bank switching in a totally *different* ROM).

That's a couple of ways, there could be dozens of others. Engineers are nothing if not sneaky :-)

Comment: Thanks. I would try the interrupt method and try to direct the slave processor to an ISR.